# T4 Run or compile tt files during runtime in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates, t4

One of my initial requirements for templating engine is that I'm able to keep the 'raw' template files (in the case .tt files) 'outside' of the library executing/transforming them with the intended purpose of allowing a developer using said library to make small adjustments to the templates if necessary depending on the requirements of what they need generated.

The library is written in C# and so far the only way I've been able to get them to work is by using default 'pre-compiled' C# class automatically generated for each template by Visual Studio.  I've had some success using the "TextTransform.exe" application to convert the .tt file directly to its intended output but this seems crude compared to a more native in code approach.

So is what I'm asking to do reasonable or did I flat out pick the wrong template engine to use for my needs?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have exactly same situation - set of T4 templates outside the main project.
But it a bit more complicated - I have some T4 templates generated on the fly.

I do try following options:

- batch (with half-manual scripting) compilation of T4 to CS and CS to DLL;
- side routine which scan given directory for T4 template and build *.csproj & *.sln for directory;
- using Visual Studio to manage and build a DLL with T4 templates.

All of those works fine, but currently I switch to the last one.

There is a reason:

- I do debug T4 templates in Visual Studio in usual way.
- I have (using T4Toolbox) highlighted T4 syntax.
- I can easily manage compilation time.

To get all of the templates in project to be recompiled prior the main Build require only 5 lines to be added at the end of the *.csproj file:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />

<PropertyGroup>
<TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
<TransformOutOfDateOnly>false</TransformOutOfDateOnly>
</PropertyGroup>
```

That's all.

After this you keep your 'raw' templates wherever you need them, organize them as normal items in DLL-type project and have an actual copy on each build.

P.S. Actual mean that if somebody change them outside the Visual Studio (in Notepad for example) you will have them all recompiled. This manageable by TransformOutOfDateOnly.

P.P.S. Have one problem with this - can't properly substitute CustomToolNamespace.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I'm interpreting your answer (please correct me if I'm wrong) as meaning that the entire DLL needs to be recompiled to account for any changes in the 'tt' files.  I was hoping I could create something like a Nuget package where you get a DLL containing some classes including a 'template transformer' class that would be called to generate the output file(s) and would include the tt files used for the basis of the transform.  Then when run the DLL would handle whatever it needs to do to perform the text transforms using the T4 file.  Does that sound possible to you?

Comment: In the provided solution every tt-file will be transformed from tt to cs/vb and result of this and any additional files (*.cs/*vb, *.resx & etc.) will be compiled into single DLL.

Comment: In the provided solution every tt-file will be transformed from tt to cs/vb and result of this and any additional files (*.cs/*vb, *.resx & etc.) will be compiled into single DLL. If you want to recompile only templates - you can separate project by two - just templates and the rest. In this way you will be able to update any template and recompile them in simple *.bat with MsBuild. But this require an almost full Visual Studio on the system.

Comment: If you willing to do full template processing on the target system you can look on TextTransfor.exe (this is TT-compiler) and after thatlook on  csc.exe (this is CS compiler) and do both stages of compilation. But I would not recommend this way - MsBuild with changes in the project file do exactly the same and much more.